# Google Drive/Doc API Remove DOCX password

Tags: google-drive-api

We are looking at a way to remove the opening password (knowing the password) from a word docx file in Google Drive API or Google Doc API.
Google Drive viewer is able to detect there is a password ask for it.
Any experience in doing so programmatically assuming the password is known?

Comment: Hi, can you provide a minimal reproducible example? How and when is the password added?

Comment: It is the standard Microsoft Words password system: Save As-> More Options -> Tools -> General Options -> Password to open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer:

It is not possible to do this programmatically, either with Drive API or Docs API. Neither of them include any way to handle passwords.

#### Feature request:

I'd suggest you to request this feature in Issue Tracker using [this template](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191650&template=824106).